# How can i add a whole folder to a zip archive

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I tried the `zip.AddDirectory` thing, but I can't figure out how to import ***a whole folder*** to an archive(Using `DotNetZip`).

I do **NOT** want this:

[image]

But this:

[image]

Comment: Do you consider a class other than `DotNetZip` but use the approach provided by .Net framework?

Answer (score 5):

From the [DotNetZip source code examples](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples) :

Remap directories. Zip up a set of files and directories, and re-map them into a different directory hierarchy in the zip file:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    // files in the filesystem like MyDocuments\ProjectX\File1.txt , will be stored in the zip archive as  backup\File1.txt
    zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX", "backup");
    // files in the filesystem like MyMusic\Santana\OyeComoVa.mp3, will be stored in the zip archive as  tunes\Santana\OyeComoVa.mp3
    zip.AddDirectory("MyMusic", "tunes");
    // The Readme.txt file in the filesystem will be stored in the zip archive as documents\Readme.txt
    zip.AddDirectory("Readme.txt", "documents");
    zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G") ; 
    zip.Save(ZipFileToCreate);
}
```